# What is the property in property binding [class.selected]?

Tags: angular

I am learning angular 2 from [official hero tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html).

```
<ul class="heroes">
      <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
        [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
        (click)="onSelect(hero)">
        <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
      </li>
</ul>
```

I've read the guide about property binding [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding), but still couldn't understand the following code:

```
[class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
```

**Question 1:**
I know html tag has a class property, but class property does not have a key called "selected". The class property may have a value, which is string "selected". How come this property binding is valid?

**Question 2:**
How does above property binding translated to class="selected" ?

Comment: The tutorial is confusing. It should be categorized as "class binding", not "property binding". You can learn more about class binding here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#class-binding

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`[class.xxx]` and `[style.xxx.yy]` are special Angular2 binding syntax where

```
[class.my-class]="expression"
```

adds (or removes) the CSS class `my-class` to (or from) the element depending on whether `expression` results in `true` or `false`

```
[style.width.px]="numExpression"
```

Sets the `width` (or any other valid style property)`to the value of`numExpression`and the unit`px` (or any other valid CSS unit)

Comment: This guide about class binding suggested by Harry Ninh, will fill my gap: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#class-binding

Comment: Excellent description of the solution

Answer (score 7):

The difference here is that `class` is not related to the HTML element, it's an angular binding. You're binding the `selected` property of Angular's `class` object to the expression, which will remove or add the property if true/false.

The property binds to `class="selected"` because when you click the `li` element, your event handler for click sets the hero, and they match.