# What does the following property binding do `[class.selected]=true`

Tags: html, angular, property-binding

I read the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737159/what-is-the-property-in-property-binding-class-selected) but that does not seem to answer my question. In one of the tutorials that I am following I came across this

```
<div class=row [class.selected]=true>
</div>
```

Now I noticed the `.selected` class declaration in the css show below

```
.selected {
 border-right : 5px solid #EEE;
 border-bottom : 5px solid #EEE;
}
```

Now my question is what does the following code do ?

```
 <div class=row [class.selected]=true>
    </div>
```

Does it replace "row" with "selected" ? What exactly happens to the html/style with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It produces

```
<div class="row selected">
</div>
```

while this code

```
<div class=row [class.selected]=false>
</div>
```

would result in

```
<div class="row">
</div>
```

Comment: hmm i thought each div can have only one class ?