# what does [class.selected] do?

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to learn angular 6, and I've come across a line of code that I don't think is well explained. It isn't producing any significant changes when being removed from the code, but is in a [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2) that I've been following. Please clear up what the following line of code does in this html file.

```
[class.selected]="atype === selectedType"
```

Full html code:

```
<h2>My Types</h2>
<ul class="types">
  <!-- Create the for loop, and then assign the selected element to the current type. -->
  <li *ngFor="let atype of types"
    [class.selected]="atype === selectedType"
    (click)="onSelect(atype)">
    <span class="badge">{{atype.id}}</span> {{atype.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

<div *ngIf="selectedType">

  <h2>{{selectedType.name | uppercase}} Details</h2>
  <div>
    <span>id: </span>{{selectedType.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name:
      <input [(ngModel)]="selectedType.name" placeholder="name">
    </label>
  </div>

</div>
```

types refers to an array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737159/what-is-the-property-in-property-binding-class-selected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the property in property binding \[class.selected\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737159/what-is-the-property-in-property-binding-class-selected)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[class.selected]="atype === selectedType"
```

Here, the condition i.e. `atype === selectedType` will be evaluated first, if it results in `true`, then the `selected css class` will be applied to the element in discussion i.e. `<li>`

This can also be written in another way:

```
[ngClass]="{'selected': atype === selectedType}"
```

This would still achieve the same. Same interpretation can be applied to  `[style.someStyleProperty]="atype === selectedType"` and [ngStyle].

Hope this helps.